# Finding out a rebus

Tags: rebus

What does the rebus mean? The rebus is as follows: It is very necessary.

[image]

Comment: It is like essential salt ( Potassium in nano grams)?!

Comment: "There's no I in King". No, that sounds wrong ...

Comment: @MOehm "There's no O in Kong".  No, that sounds even wore.

Comment: It's really agonizing to realise how close to working "agonizing" is.

Comment: In the land of the eyeless, the one-eyed king is a man.

Comment: @DavidStarkey "There's no lion in Klingon"? It does look like the space between the "K" and "ng" is too big for just an "i".

Comment: @Hmm, looks like this is unlikely to ever have a correct answer marked or provided by the asker. (User last active Dec. 25th, 2017.) Oh well. I interpreted "It is very necessary" as meaning the exact presentation was important, so I figured they had access to the answer themselves. Unless (since it follows the colon) they were saying "It is very necessary." is part of the rebus...

Answer (score 13):

It could be a

> Selfless King!

As,

> One meaning of self is I and selfless is opposite of selfishness and it is very necessary.

Comment: Or maybe an eyeless king.

Answer (score 11):

It is obviously

> **Brainy Smurf** (*Schtroumpf à Lunettes* in the original french version).

Explanation :

> This is a king missing an I (or an eye). And as we know it : *in the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king*.
>
> So, this is a kingdom full of blind people. Also, the king is **blue**. The only logical explanation is that this is the Smurf village where all Smurfs went blind (because of some Gargamel's trick or whatever). And which Smurf managed to keep at least an eye in working condition ? The one wearing eye-protection of course. Glasses.
>
> Hence : Brainy Smurf.

Comment: But this king has No “I”...

Comment: Or one missing "I"

Comment: It only has one I. So “KING” is the king with one I

Answer (score 5):

A possible answer is:

> A just king.

Or even

> A just king with perspective.

Explanation:

> The king has no "i" (or "no eye") and as justice is blind, so is the king —a just king. And there is the possible addition of the word "perspective" as the letters are shown at a perspective angle. And I would say "It is very necessary" for a king to be just and have perspective.

Another possible variant:

> A king with a just perspective.

Comment: Not fair Hawk**EYE**. Not fair.

Answer (score 5):

My 1st answer: it means

> "Real king"

Explanation:

> It's King divided by $i$, the imaginary unit. So, a real number is left.

Answer (score 3):

> Elvis has left the blued i in "ing"

because

> "The King" has left out the expected blue-outlined "i" in the "ing" part

Answer (score 1):

It is

> Blind King

Because,

> Because there is no 'I', which pronounciation is similar to 'eye'.