# Eight Kings Problem

Tags: rebus

Went through approximately six trillion words ending in "king" while trying to figure out [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58293/finding-out-a-rebus). Couldn't find one that would fit. Not willing to let the effort go to waste, here are 8 of them, presented by chess kings.

[image]

This time around, the clues are sometimes phonetic, sometimes literal, and there's even one direct hint. If a clue happens to fit more than one word, any one of them will do.

**To reiterate, we are looking for 8 more or less random English words, each one ending in "king".**

Comment: Just to confirm... That invisible one is intended, right?

Comment: @Lolgast D4 is empty very much on purpose, yes.

Comment: Thought as much. No clue what it is yet, but still.

Comment: By "8 Kings Problem" I thought of the problem of placing 8 kings on the chess board so that none of them attack any other. Utterly trivial of course, although *counting* the number of solutions sounds nontrivial.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Respectively

> `c8`: hiking ("high king")
> `f7`: barking ("bar king")?
> `h6`: liking ("lie king")
> `a5`: banking ("ban king")
> `g3`: winking ("win king")
> `e2`: funking ("fun king")?, or seeking ("see king"; credit to Lawrence)
> `b1`: thinking ("thin king")
> `outside`: awaking ("away king")

Comment: Woops, guess I didn't look carefully enough when editing... the king on the `a` line is on the *5th* row, and on `h` it's the *6th* row. Also, based on the famous [eight queen puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), the missing one should be on `d4`

Comment: I'd love to think that the invisible king is the _troublemaking_, because he's away, probably doing something nasty. But your solution is more fitting ;)

Comment: Maybe e2 is cooking (cool king)?

Comment: e2 - seeking (see king)?

Comment: H6 could be "flunking"

Comment: Awaking inside!

Comment: I wonder if it might be good to have one with a donkey (while making inquiries), and one cavorting with loose queens (while underwater)?  Perhaps add one with a *talkative* donkey (while slowing down)?

Comment: ...or possibly knocking (no king)

Comment: d4 could also be lacking ("lack king").

Comment: I had another idea for e2, but yeah, those would work too. The rest are exactly what I planned, so have a tick!

Comment: @supercat, all of those got rejected on the account of being approx 7 orders of magnitude over the complexity level I can draw in Gimp. Other rejects include a custard tart, half a bottle of vodka surprisingly from an UK company, and not from Highgarden) and a movie.

Comment: @Bass: I don't get any of yours.  In my additional "suggestions", the parenthetical phrase applies to the word formed by combining the former part with "king"; did you figure those out?

Comment: @supercat, those would have been ”flan”, ”smir”(noff) and the rather less clever ”flick”. No, I didn’t really figure yours out, since I had gone through similar thought processes twice already, and ended up with the same exact clues for them :-)

Comment: @Bass: Well in case anyone else was wondering, mine were as-, sin-, and bra-.

Answer (score 3):

Other ideas:

> c8: seeking (the king in column c)
>  f7: blacking (but really *liked* masking most...brilliant)
>  h6: taking (an extra one)
>  a5: aching (the king in column a)
>  g3: thanking (acceptance speech)
>  e2: spiking ("spy king")
>  b1: talking ("tall king")
>  d4: remarking (see comments...but "awaking" was brilliant)

Comment: These are quite excellent! The other answer hit the ones I intended (except e2. which you got) so I can only offer the uppest of my upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Only four:

> f7 is masking himself
>  h6 is mistaking 5 for 4 in the calculation
>  e2 is blocking sunlight from hurting his eyes
>  someone is striking a5 out